# How can I get this stored procedure to execute a CALL when the condition is not equal?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a quick question about MySql.  I have this simple store procedure, that I would like to make a CALL to two store procedures when the condition is met.
The variable @SDOuser is assigned the User ID when the access level is 10 and the timestamp evaluates to the login time of between now and 2 seconds ago.  Once I have this set, I then want to use it as the condition for my IF block.  Here lies the issue, it works fine when the first block stays TRUE and nothing follows.  But, I need the Users who have access level that is less than 10 and it does not seem to like the negating the condition to get to that.

Here is the code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE `getPositionGrid`//
CREATE DEFINER=<some name>  PROCEDURE `getPositionGrid`()
BEGIN   



  set @SDOuser = (SELECT DISTINCT(uu.uu_id) FROM tbl_logins ul 
                            INNER JOIN tbl_users uu
                            ON ul.ul_username = uu.uu_email

                            inner join tbl_access_level al
                            on al.al_id = uu.al_id
                            inner join tbl_positions up
                            on up.up_id = uu.up_id
                            inner join tbl_departments ud
                            on up.ud_id = ud.ud_id

  WHERE ul.ul_created  BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 2 SECOND AND NOW());
  set @CurrUser = (select uu_id from tbl_users where al_id = 10 AND uu_id = @SDOuser);
  set @CurrUser1 = (select uu_id from tbl_users where al_id < 10 AND uu_id != @SDOuser);


  IF(@CurrUser) THEN  
    BEGIN
     CALL getPositionGridSDO();
    END;
  END IF;
  IF(@CurrUser1) THEN  
    BEGIN
     CALL getPositionGridALL();
    END;
  END IF;

END
```

//

Comment: I tried an IF ELSE structure but had no luck, don't know if the syntax I was using was correct..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF (@CurrUser IS NOT NULL) THEN  
    BEGIN
     CALL getPositionGridSDO();
    END;
END IF;
IF(@CurrUser1 IS NOT NULL) THEN  
    BEGIN
     CALL getPositionGridALL();
    END;
END IF;
```

Alternatively:

```
IF (@CurrUser > 0) THEN  
...
END IF;
IF(@CurrUser1 > 0) THEN  
...
END IF;
```

Hope it helps!